# Comparing long exact sequences for local cohomology

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, local-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space, $Z_1,Z_2 \subset X$ closed subsets and $\mathcal{F} \in Sh(X)$.

Then we have, for example by Hartshorne Excercise III 2.4, the Mayer Vietoris sequence for local cohomology
\begin{equation*}
\ldots \rightarrow H^i_{Z_1 \cap Z_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^i_{Z_1}(X,\mathcal{F}) \oplus H^i_{Z_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow H^i_{Z_1 \cup Z_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \stackrel{\delta}{\rightarrow}  H^{i+1}_{Z_1 \cap Z_2}(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow\ldots 
\end{equation*}

Additionally we have the long exact sequence

\begin{equation*}
\ldots \rightarrow H^i_{Z_1 \cap Z_2}(X,\mathcal{F}) \rightarrow  H^i_{Z_1 \cup Z_2 }(X,\mathcal{F}) \stackrel{f}{\rightarrow} H^i_{{(Z_1 \cup Z_2) \backslash (Z_1 \cap Z_2)}}(X,\mathcal{F}) \stackrel{g}{\rightarrow}  H^{i+1}_{Z_1 \cap Z_2}(X,\mathcal{F})\rightarrow\ldots 
\end{equation*}

Does then by any chance  $\delta=g\circ f=0 $ hold?